# What is Ideal way to create session factory and use it in multiple DAO methods of Multiple DAO's?

Tags: hibernate

I want to create session factory and share it in multiple DAO instead of creating it in individual DAO.
Please suggest me ideal way

Answer (score 0):

Define a spring bean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
...
```

Then introduce a BaseDAO class where you can utowire the factory

```
@Autowired 
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

So all your DAOs extending the BaseDAO have access to the same factory.

Comment: I am using Annotation based configuration.still I can use same ?

Comment: Of course you can in your ConfigurationContext use  @Bean
 //@Scope("project") if necessary
 public SessionFactory sessionFactory() { //init it here. e.g set DataSource etc.

Comment: I am using below method in my HibernateConfiguration class:-        @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
       sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.logistica.common.entity" });
       sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
       return sessionFactory;
    }        is it fine?

Comment: Looks fine. Can't you just try?